# Duplicate value on record: on Custom Metadata for deleted record

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata, installedpackage

I have a managed package, beta version, installed in an org. There is a Custom Metadata type with a custom field that is set to Unique Values. I created a record and had a unique value of '15' in that field. Then I uninstalled the package and deleted all the data and then installed a newer beta version. When I try to create a record for the metadata type and have a value of '15' in that unique field, I get an error of: "Error: Duplicate value on record: m0c0D000xxxxxx" where "m0c0D000xxxxxx" is not a record that I can see in the org at all. It doesn't show up under any SOQL queries. I confirmed "m0c0D000xxxxxx" has the sObjectType of the metadata I am querying and creating. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I would guess this is because the data deletions and package uninstall are in the "recycle bin"...? Alternatively, the package includes some protected CMT records - not visible on the org outside the package namespace or via "subscriber login" from your PBO - that happens to have "15" in this field.

Comment: That was my guess regarding the "recycle bin" but I did remember to select "Do not save a copy of this package's data after uninstall". The CMT was also set to Public, the records created were not listed as Protected, and the Field Manageability was set to "Subscriber editable". So no clue

Comment: While I was not able to determine the reason this happened, I was able to uninstall and reinstall the package and that resolved the issue. A bit of a hassle, but it did work.